# Compiling .jar from .java with dependencies

Tags: java

I've got a single .java file that I'm trying to compile into a .jar file, but it has several import statements that I believe is causing it to not run once compiled.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
```

Do I need to include each of these in the build compile separately or is there something else I need to do?

This is what I'm doing in cmd to try and compile it.

```
javac -d ./build wallPricing.java
```

Then

```
jar cvf wallPricing.jar wallPricing.class wallPricing$BtnListener.class
```

Note: The program was made in JDK 13.0.1

Edit:
I get these warnings after running the first command to create .class files

```
                Double NUM_A = new Double(ITEM_A.getText());
                               ^
wallPricing.java:91: warning: [removal] Double(String) in Double has been deprecated and marked for removal
                Double NUM_B = new Double(ITEM_B.getText());
                               ^
wallPricing.java:92: warning: [removal] Double(String) in Double has been deprecated and marked for removal
                Double NUM_C = new Double(ITEM_C.getText());
                               ^
wallPricing.java:93: warning: [removal] Double(String) in Double has been deprecated and marked for removal
                Double NUM_D = new Double(ITEM_D.getText());
                               ^
wallPricing.java:94: warning: [removal] Double(String) in Double has been deprecated and marked for removal
                Double NUM_E = new Double(ITEM_E.getText());
                               ^
```

Edit 2:
This is the output after running the second command to create the .jar file

```
added manifest
adding: wallPricing.class(in = 2056) (out= 1185)(deflated 42%)
adding: wallPricing$BtnListener.class(in = 1216) (out= 709)(deflated 41%)
```

Comment: What error do you get? Are you running the jar command in the build directory, where you told the compiler to put the class files?

Comment: I will edit the post to show which warnings I get after running the first command to create the .class files in the build directory. -- I am aware what these warnings are from, but I never assumed them to be a cause of the program not running at all. Also, I am running the next command in the build directory, and I do get a .jar file output.

Comment: Warnings don't prevent a class from compiling or running. In the future `new Double(String)` should be replaced by `Double.valueOf(String)`, and you can get a jump on that by making that change now, but these warnings will not prevent your program from working.

Comment: Did you get any error when you ran the jar file?

Comment: No errors. I ran the file and nothing happened. It makes me think that maybe the classes I'm importing from Java aren't being included in this.

Comment: Those classes come with the JVM. What happens if you run it directly with `java wallPricing`, not via the jar file. (By the way, classes normally begin with a capital letter in Java.)

Comment: When I run it normally from my IDE (Intellij IDEA), it runs as it should.